# How to correctly convert an array in PHP with quantity/price data?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

I am given an array in PHP that looks something like this:

```
array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 50,
        1 => 0.80
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 300,
        1 => 0.50
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => 600,
        1 => 0.30
    ),
    3 => array (
        0 => 1000,
        1 => 0.20
    ),
    4 => array (
        0 => 4000,
        1 => 0.10
    )
);
```

An array of arrays where the first index of the inner array represents a quantity while the second index represents a price.

I want to import this data into my database, but in a specific way.

I have specific quantities that I like to keep track of that are defined by the following array:

```
array(10,100,500,1000,5000,10000);
```

I then want to make the original array more fine tuned to quantities and prices that I would like to see. So in this particular example, I would like an array that looks like this:

```
array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 100,
        1 => 0.80
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 500,
        1 => 0.50
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => 1000,
        1 => 0.20
    ),
    3 => array (
        0 => 5000,
        1 => 0.10
    )
);
```

My new array will only contain the specific quantity indexes.
If a quantity exists in the original array, I use that price. If it doesn't exist, I would use the price of the next lowest quantity. If no lower quantity exists, I don't want to see that quantity in the new array.

I have been able to accomplish what I want for the most part with the following code:

```
    function getRelativePrices($pricearray) {
    $relativeprices = array();
    $types = array(10,100,500,1000,5000,10000);
    foreach ($types as $q) {
        $new_array = array();
        foreach ($pricearray as $index => $array) {
            if ($q >= $array[0]) {
                $new_array = array($q, $array[1]);
            }
        }
        if (sizeof($new_array)) {
            $relativeprices[] = $new_array;
        }
    }
    return $relativeprices;
}
```

The only problem with the above is that I am getting extra data that I do not want. In the example I provided, I am getting a 5th index/array at the end that looks like:

```
4 => array (
    0 => 10000,
    1 => 0.10
)
```

I don't want this last piece, since I find it redundant considering that I know that 5000 pieces cost $0.10 each, so I can assume that 10000 will cost the same price when "4000" is the highest quantity given in the original array.

So I want to ask for help in removing this last piece.
Also, I was wondering if someone had a better coding method in general for converting this array.

Comment: You should change your array to `array (
    0 => array (
        'quantity' => 50,
        'price' => 0.80
    )`
So it's easier to see, but it's really up to you

Comment: Well, I use a REST call which gives me the array in that format. Because I want to display HTML tables of both the original array as well as the reformatted one, I'm probably not going to change the structure of the reformatted array. But yea, I usually like to use keys when I can.

Comment: I think you need to loop through the given array and then check it against the types array. See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do in your inner foreach:

```
foreach ($pricearray as $index => $array) {
            if ($q >= $array[0]) {
                if($q == 10000) { continue; }
                $new_array = array($q, $array[1]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm usually not good at explaining my problem fully.
It needs to be general in the sense that I might get an array tat only contains 100 and 500 quantities. In this case, I don't want to see any quantities in my new array that are greater than 500.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think this should do the trick. I think the problem was in your comparison... See code:

```
function getRelativePrices($pricearray) {
    $relativeprices= array();
    $types = array(10,100,500,1000,5000,10000);
    foreach($pricearray as $p) {
        $new_array = array();
        foreach($types as $t) {
            if($p[0] <= $t) {
                $new_array = array($t,$p[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(sizeof($new_array)) {
            $relativeprices[] = $new_array;
        }
    }
    return $relativeprices;
}
```

Here is an example of my test based on your code examples:

```
function getRelativePrices($pricearray) {
    $relativeprices= array();
    $types = array(10,100,500,1000,5000,10000);
    foreach($pricearray as $p) {
        $new_array = array();
        foreach($types as $t) {
            if($p[0] <= $t) {
                $new_array = array($t,$p[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(sizeof($new_array)) {
            $relativeprices[] = $new_array;
        }
    }
    return $relativeprices;
}


$test = array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 50,
        1 => 0.80
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 300,
        1 => 0.50
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => 600,
        1 => 0.30
    ),
    3 => array (
        0 => 1000,
        1 => 0.20
    ),
    4 => array (
        0 => 4000,
        1 => 0.10
    )
);

print_r(getRelativePrices($test));
```

And the output was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 0.8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 0.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 0.3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 0.2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 0.1
        )

)
```